# Setting default path when opening a terminal session

Tags: command-line, bash, filesystem

I am new to Ubuntu.

Whenever I open a terminal my current working directory `/home/Varun` (as found by typing `pwd`).

Is there any way I can make the terminal's path to be set as `/home/Varun/Desktop/Java Files` when it opens?

Comment: What terminal do you use?

Comment: Related, at least somewhat: [How do I enter a directory on a different hard drive using cd in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950982/how-do-i-enter-a-directory-on-a-different-hard-drive-using-cd-in-the-terminal)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just run the following command in your terminal:

```
echo "cd ~/Desktop/Java\ Files" >> ~/.bashrc
```

The above command will add a new line in your `~/.bashrc` file that contain `cd ~/Desktop/Java\ Files` and that will change your default working directory to `/home/Varun/Desktop/Java Files` when you will open the terminal.

Reopen the terminal and you will see the difference.

Comment: But whenever you need open through a file manager, it'll still open the path you gave in ~/.bashrc file. So, this is not the best option.

Comment: tilix -e "bash --rcfile 'my rc file' "
Substitute tilix with the terminal emulator that you use.

Comment: The contents of my rc while should be:
`. "~/.bashrc"`  `cd ~/something`

Answer (score 12):

You can add the following line to the end of your `~/.bashrc`

`cd ~/Desktop/Java\ Files`

Answer (score 6):

Although changing the `$HOME` variable and calling `cd` command (i'll use cmd for short) in `.bashrc` file is right answer to your question,

i find it more comfortable to create alias (for example `cdh`) which takes me directly to directory i want.

The reason is that all files which configures other programs (Just like `.bashrc` for example) stay in default `$HOME` directory and i can work in my "`cdh` directory" without interuption from theese files.

If i needed to go back to `$HOME` directory i can allways use `cd` cmd.

> In some linux distros the `.bashrc` file is shipped with command or commands which runs or run one or multiple other files intended for that specific use (for example `.bash_aliases`)
>
> so decide for yourself if you want to use them or not,
>
> in case you want to use them, just use it the same as you use `.bashrc` but with commands inteded for the specified file.

so in `.bashrc` (or in `.bash_aliases` or whichever file you've chosen)

write following:

```
alias cdh='cd /home/Varun/Desktop/Java Files'
```

> if you don't like `cdh` alias don't be afraid to use different name but make sure there isn't any other cmd or alias named like this, couse you could make that cmd more or less unusable.
>
> You can check if the name is taken by triyng to call it but i would sugest a `type` cmd with argument of name of another cmd.
>
> The `type` cmd should tell you if the given cmd is alias, binary file, or bash script, or ......... whatever. And therefore will tell you when cmd doesn't exist. (Which is what you want in this case)

Comment: Sorry if i made any mistake. Im not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 5):

While putting `cd ~/Desktop/Java\ Files` into the `.bashrc` file does work, it has the terrible side-effect of overriding the Nautilus *Open in Terminal* action, so you can no longer open any other sub-folder in a terminal.

My solution is to change the Keyboard Shortcut in Settings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to run this command:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --working-directory="/home/butch/Documents"
```

This will open new terminal windows in my `Documents` folder, while allowing Nautilus to open new terminal windows wherever.

Note this command does not accept `~/Documents`, the full path must be specified.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file.
If you open terminal from nautilus in your home directory, it will unfortunately still cd. I'm not sure how escaping works, but this might not work if your current directory or home directory has unescaped characters.

```
if [ "$PWD" == "$HOME" ]; then cd Desktop/Java\ Files/; fi
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Just to add**

If someone is using **[zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH)** shell than

```
nano ~/.zshrc ( open the configuration file)
```

and at bootom add

```
cd ~/Desktop/Java\ Files
```

so the tweak is what ever shell you are using `(echo $0 )` just add the command you usually use and it will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know what shell you are using. Acces the `rc` file of that shell. In normal Ubuntu shell, it is `~/.bashrc` and in zsh shell it is `~/.zshrc`. Then add a line at the bottom that says:

```
cd <Destination>
```

For a windows destination, use `/mnt/<harddrive>`. For a Ubuntu destination, just use `~<destination>`.

Example(zsh shell and windows path):

```
vim ~/.zshrc
cd /mnt/c/Desktop
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Terminal has an option within the user's profiles called "Preserve working directory" and probably this is what you need to tweak.

[image]

*I'm posting this here, because one more suitable [Terminal opens in incorrect directory](https://askubuntu.com/q/1425582/566421) is marked as duplication of this one.*