# Terminal opens in incorrect directory

Tags: command-line, 22.04

When I open terminal using the applications menu or using search, it always opens in `~/Documents/GitHub`. How do I make it open in `~`?

Comment: Which version and flavour of Ubuntu are you using? (For example Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.4 LTS or Lubuntu 22.04.1 LTS). It helps us help you to know this. Otherwise we can only give you a general answer, that may not be best fit for your version and flavour.

Comment: Yes, that linked worked a treat, thanks alot.

Comment: I've added an [answer for GNOME Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/1426472/566421) to the duplication topic.